# Css flex box make the second element centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have simple layout that i need the h3 in the left side and the nav in the right side but at center, i want to do this with flex box but i does not know how to make the nav to be centered on the right.

In regular grid this was like the h3 is width of 30% and the nav width 70% and you give the nav text align: center.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  paddding: 0;
}

header {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h3>hello</h3>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Tab1</li>
      <li>Tab2</li>
      <li>Tab3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to the nav margin: auto

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  paddding: 0;
}
header {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h3>hello</h3>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks this exactly what i want.